# How to check wheather all form fields contain a value with jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I need away to know if all fields have a value and if they do, I want to activate the submit button.

I have looked at plugins but I don't know which one I need/should use.

The form uses `input`, `textbox` and `dropdown selects`.

Comment: What about [Validate.JS](http://rickharrison.github.com/validate.js/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use a plugin you could do something simple like this (note: I haven't tested this):

```
/**
 * Checks to see if all of the values in a form are filled in.
 *
 * @param formId String the id of the form to check (without the #)
 * @return boolean True indicates all form fields are filled in
 */
function checkForm(formId){

  var isFormComplete = true;

  $('#' + formId).find('input,select,textarea').each(function(){
      var formValue = jQuery.trim($(this).val());

      if(!formValue){
          isFormComplete = false;
      }
  });

  return isFormComplete;
}
```

and then on some event (probably `focus` or `blur`) you call this function, and toggle the submit button based on the return value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to select the controls you want via their id.  I would suggest this over having to support a plugin--which could essentially be a black box to you.

markup:

```
<input type="text" id="myTextBox" />
 <input type="text" id="x" />
 <select id="y" />
```

jquery:

```
var valid = $("#myTextBox").val() != "" &&
            $("#x").val() != "" &&
            $("#y").selectedIndex != 0; // if zero would be invalid for a select...
```

You can enable / disable your submit button based on valid.

Comment: `val()` is falsy...`$el.val() != ''` --> `!$el.val()`

Answer (score 0):

```
var $submit = $('#a-form').find('input[type="submit"]'),
    $inputs = $('#a-form').find('input, textarea').not('[type="submit"], [type="hidden"]');
$inputs.on('change', function () {
    var error = false;
    $.each($inputs, function (index, element) {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            error = true;
            $(this).css({ backgroundColor : 'red' });
        } else {
            $(this).css({ backgroundColor : 'white' });
        }
    });
    if (error) {
        $submit.prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $submit.prop('disabled', false);
    }
});​
```

This binds an event handler to the inputs a form for the `change` event that checks the value of each input in the form, if any are blank then the submit button is disabled. It also changes the `background-color` of any blank inputs to `red`.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2zjbM/1/